# How can an Android emulator find out its port number?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need a piece of code that can return the emulator port through which it has connected to my host machine. 
I know it usually starts with 5554, 5556 etc. but is it possible for an application running inside the emulator to know its port number?

thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to know that?

Comment: @Henry a number of client emulators need to connect to a server. I want to use the port number as clientID when the emulator introduces itself to the server.